# Contact form not delivering to my email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mail-form

I am using mail form and simple form to create a contact form for my website. I have used Mandrill as my email delivery service. Everything appears to be working fine according to my logs, but I do not get an email delivered to me when I do this.

```
MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 359.2ms

Sent mail to example@gmail.com (787.8ms)
Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 13:20:59 -0500
From: "New ABA Conact Form Submission"
To: example@gmail.com
Message-ID: <message id>
Subject: My Contact Form
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h4 style="text-decoration:underline">My Contact Form</h4>


  <p><b>Email:</b>
  example@aol.com</p>
```

Where I have 'example@gmail.com' is where my actual email is declared and it is entered correctly. I am working in a development environment. Do you guys know why I am not receiving the messages?

Comment: Are you using a production key for Mandrill or a test key? The latter don't actually send e-mail.

Comment: My guess is that your config/environments/development.rb file is not set up to send mail, but to use a test mode on localhost

Comment: You both make valid points that are equally correct, thanks for shedding some light.